# PHP: SOAP Webservice working not properly

Tags: php, web-services, soap

i'll change function name is 'price' its work perfectly but other name give           it it's occur error like below

function-->

```
<?php
   function facto($name)
   {
      $details= array('abc' =>100 ,'xyz'=>210 );
      foreach ($details as $n => $p) {
               if($name==$n)
               $price=$p+100;
      }
      return $price;
    }
 ?>
```

client-->

```
<?php
require 'lib/nusoap.php';
$client=new  nusoap_client("http://localhost/WebServicePHP/service1.php?wsdl");
$book_name="abc";
$response=$client->call('facto',array("name"=>"$book_name"));
if(empty($response))
    echo "Book data not available";
else
    echo $response;
?>
```

service -->

```
<?php
require 'functions.php';
require 'lib/nusoap.php';
$server=new nusoap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("demo","urn:demo");
$server- >register("facto",array("name"=>'xsd:string'),
    array("return"=>'xsd:intger'));

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA=isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)?
  $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA:'';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); 
?>
```

now its return error like

> "Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\WebServiceExp\factclient.php on line 9 Array"

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing an array in argument and compare that array as string in `if` condition.

so change this line :

`$response=$client->call('facto',array("name"=>"$book_name"));`

to this :

```
$response=$client->call('facto',$book_name);
```

OR change your if condition from this :

```
if($name==$n)
```

to this :

```
if(in_array($n,$name))
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\WebServiceExp\factclient.php on line 9 Array"

Your problem on 9 line of your client code where you try to echo array `echo $response;`. Change it to `var_dump($response);` to see structure of this array and then echo appropriate value from this array